# Basemap Scatter not plotting correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, coordinates, matplotlib-basemap

Basically I have a csv filled with latitude and longitude data that I'm adding to two separate columns in the data frame. Then using that to create a globe with all the data plotted. Except the data isn't plotting correctly and I have no idea why.

Reading in the data file and adding it to csv.

```
data_col = ['IP', 'Reliability', 'Risk', 'Type', 'Country', 'Locale', 'Co-Ords', '?'] 
data = pd.read_csv('reputation.data', sep='#', names=data_col)
```

Taking the Co-Ords column and splitting it to two different columns

```
data['Co-Ords'] = data['Co-Ords'].str.replace('ut: ','')
data['lat'] = data['Co-Ords'].apply( lambda x: x.split(',')[0] )
data['lon'] = data['Co-Ords'].apply( lambda x: x.split(',')[1] )
```

Implementing the data to basemap;

```
m1 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lon_0=4,lat_0=46, resolution='l')

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

m1.drawmapboundary(fill_color='black')
m1.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='black')
m1.drawcoastlines()
m1.drawcountries()

x=(data['lat']).as_matrix()
y=(data['lon']).as_matrix()

m1.scatter(x,y,cmap=cm.cool,marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, 
latlon=True, zorder=10)
plt.title("IP Addresses on the Globe")
plt.show()
```

And it looks like the following:
[Globe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzyqO.png)

Appreciate the help.

Edit: The data that I'm reading from

```
IP  Reliability Risk    Type    Country Locale  Co-Ords ?   lat lon
46.4.123.15 4   2   Malicious   DE  NaN 51.0,9.0    3   51  9
116.117.253.243 3   2   Scanning    CN  Baotou  40.6521987915,109.82219696  11  40.6521987915   109.82219696
123.59.59.89    4   2   Malicious   CN  Beijing 39.9289016724,116.388298035 3   39.9289016724   116.388298035
123.59.71.2 4   2   Malicious   CN  Beijing 39.9289016724,116.388298035 3   39.9289016724   116.388298035
123.59.149.74   4   2   Malicious   CN  Beijing 39.9289016724,116.388298035 3   39.9289016724   116.388298035
```

Comment: Could you share a snippet, 5-10 rows of your data, where you annotate in which country the data points are expected to appear?

Comment: [Yea, it looks like the following](http://i.imgur.com/9Cv0PYE.png)

Comment: Thanks, could you append that output as text to the question, so that it is easy to copy? You can do `print(data.head())`, and just copy it over here. Also, did you plot this subset to confirm that these points are also misplaced on the map?

Comment: Just added it to the post

Comment: And I took one set longitude and latitude and placed it on my globe, and used google maps to confirm if it was in the correct area. Hence I know why the data isn't popping up in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [convert your longitude and latitude to map coordinates](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html) via `x, y = m1(x, y)`. In the code below, I replaced that line and your matrix conversion with this one line, which I think is clearer: `y,x = m1(data['lon'].values, data['lat'].values)`

This code is working for me

```
m1 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lon_0=4,lat_0=46, resolution='l')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

m1.drawmapboundary(fill_color='black')
m1.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='black')
m1.drawcoastlines()
m1.drawcountries()

x,y = m1(data['lon'].values, data['lat'].values)
m1.scatter(x,y, marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, zorder=10)

plt.title("IP Addresses on the Globe")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, fixed it. I tried something similar but I'm guessing the .values() part corrected how the values should of been read?

Comment: @A.Timmins Yes, I also noted that it did not work passing the column from the data frame directly as a Series, `.values()` converts it into a numpy array.